# Unable to save data on heroku in android studio

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I deployed Parse Server example (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) to Heroku. After following many tutorials, I tried to save a simple data onto the MongoDB add-on in Heroku but I get a Save Failed message according to my code i demanded Save Failed or Save Succeeded. I also checked it on the Parse-Dashboard locally as well as from the MongoDB website, but i got nothing over there.
Here is my Code:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.parsedemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

StarterApplication.java:

```
package com.example.parsedemo;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class StarterApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .applicationId("instagram666666")
                    .clientKey(null)
                    .server("http://instagram666666.herokuapp.com/parse/")
                    .build()
    );

    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
    gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
            } else {
                Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
            }
        }
    });


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}

}
```

Gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.parsedemo"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/parse-android-1.13.1.jar')
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.parsedemo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name= '.StarterApplication'>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also imported required libraries as required, but still unable to Save data on the DB. I've been stuck here for around a week!
I am using version 1.5 of Android Studio.

Comment: I checked all the keys billion times and they are correct. You can use my keys and try if it works with you.

Comment: Can you please change http:// to https:// and retest it?

Comment: It didn't worked....

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the database to your application using the Heroku command line interface.

Follow these steps:

1. Download and install or open the Heroku CLI if already installed.
2. Type heroku login and press enter to open a browser and login with your Heroku credentials.
3. The CLI should now say "logged in as YourHerokuUsername@YourEmail.com"
4. Copy the mongoDB link (`db_link`) from your apps' settings on Heroku dashboard
5. Now type in `heroku config:set DATABASE_URI=db_link -a app_name` where `app_name` is the name of the application you want to link with your database.
6. Run your project again & your log should now say "Save Succeeded."
7. Open your database using the Heroku dashboard for the app you just linked with the database to see your ParseObject stored under collections.